# Sending multiple media messages on whatsapp with twilio sandbox

Tags: java, twilio, whatsapp

I'm Using Twilio sandbox to send media files to a WhatsApp number.

When I tried multiple media URI's, I received only one random file.

I'm able to send one file successfully.

```java
List<URI> uriList = new ArrayList<URI>();
for (String uriStr : requestVO.getUri()) {
    uriList.add(URI.create(uriStr));
}
message = Message
        .creator(
                new PhoneNumber(CommonMethods.formatMobileNumber(requestVO.getTo(),
                        WhatsappConstants.COUNTRY_CODE_IND)),
                new PhoneNumber(CommonMethods.formatMobileNumber(WhatsappConstants.FROM_NUMBER,
                        WhatsappConstants.COUNTRY_CODE_US)),
                requestVO.getMessage())
        .setMediaUrl(uriList).create();
```

Answer (score 4):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

Twilio Whatsapp doesn't support sending more than one media attachment in a single message.

[Quoting the official website](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#sending-a-freeform-whatsapp-message-with-media-attachment):

> One media attachment is supported per message, with a size limit of 5MB.

To come around this you have to send each media URL with its own message.

Comment: Thanks for your help..  But setMediaUrl() is accepting a URL list, any reason for that ?

Comment: That something if have to check... I'll come back to you. :)

Comment: Stefan is correct - only one MediaUrl is supported for WhatsApp. The reason that the Message.creator() can take a List is because you can also send MMS with this class, which can take up to ten MediaUrls. You will see an error related to that if you add a list with eleven or more items, and it should be an error to have more than one if the destination number is a WA number. We are tracking this internally as a bug in the API. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Even though we can include multiple URLs in media_url (list of urls) but Twilio WhatsApp API does not allows you to send more than one media file in a message. Each file must be <16 MB size.

[Guidance on WhatsApp Media Messages from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/guidance-whatsapp-media-messages)

```
message = client.messages \
.create(
     media_url = [
         'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__480.jpg',
         'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/13/12/26/aurora-1197753__480.jpg',
         ],
     from_ = settings.REGISTERED_NUMBER,
     body = "Some msg",
     to = 'whatsapp:+12345678900'
 )
```

In the above snippet, only the first file will be send and second file will be enqueued.